# Spring boot - security java config - LDAP

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

I am trying to set up ldap authentication through java config. The code auth.getObject inside the method init returns null and unable to set the authentication manager and also no exception is seen. Is there anything wrong in the config?  How can i get the authentication manager object?

```
@Configuration
    public class LdapAuthenticationConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        /** The environment. */
        private Environment environment;

        @Bean(name="ldapAuthManager")
        public AuthenticationManager getAuthManager(){
            return authenticationManager;
        }

        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userSearchFilter(
                            "(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0})(objectclass=organizationalPerson))")
                    .userSearchBase("OU="+environment.getProperty("ldap.user-search-base.name"))
                    .groupSearchFilter("(member={0})")
                    .groupSearchBase("OU=Global-Groups").groupRoleAttribute("cn")
                    .contextSource().url(environment.getProperty("ldap.url"))
                    .managerDn(environment.getProperty("ldap.conn.user"))
                    .managerPassword(environment.getProperty("ldap.conn.pwd"));

            setAuthenticationManager(auth.getObject());

        }

        public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() {
            return authenticationManager;
        }

        public void setAuthenticationManager(
                AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        }

        @Autowired
        public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {

            this.environment = environment;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add complete URL to LDAP server for "ldap.url" with port and searchBase, eg: `ldap://**server name**:**port**/**o=userSearchBase**`

It worked for me. For some reasen `.port()` and `.userSearchBase()` didn't work to build the correct url.

Hope it helps.